# Display all table data through procedures in SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a employees table and i have to print all employees data through a procedure I tried this:

```
DECLARE
e_ename Emp.Empname%Type;
e_job Emp.Job%Type;
e_mgr Emp.Mgr%Type;
e_hiredate Emp.Hiredate%Type;
e_sal Emp.Sal%Type;
e_comm Emp.Comm%Type;

PROCEDURE empregados(n IN Emp.Empname%Type, j IN
Emp.Job%Type, m IN Emp.Mgr%Type, h IN Emp.Hiredate%Type, s IN Emp.Sal%Type, cm IN Emp.Comm%Type)
IS

BEGIN

    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Name: ' || n ||' Job: '||j||'MGR: '||m||' Hiredate: '||h||' Salary: '||s||' Comissao: '||cm);

END;
BEGIN
SELECT ENAME into e_ename, job into e_job, mgr into e_mgr, hiredate into e_hiredate, sal into e_sal, comm into e_comm FROM EMP;
empregados(e_ename,e_job,e_mgr,e_hiredate,e_sal,e_comm);
END;
/
```

Im having some trouble with this error

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 19, column 32:
PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
ORA-06550: line 19, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Would like to know what is wrong in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to specify `into` once. Your statement should look like

```sql
select col1, col2, col3
  into var1, var2, var3
  from emp
 where emp_id = 123;
```

To print out all employee info, you can loop through the employees using a cursor

```sql
DECLARE
    PROCEDURE empregados (n    IN Emp.Empname%TYPE,
                          j    IN Emp.Job%TYPE,
                          m    IN Emp.Mgr%TYPE,
                          h    IN Emp.Hiredate%TYPE,
                          s    IN Emp.Sal%TYPE,
                          cm   IN Emp.Comm%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line (
               'Name: '
            || n
            || ' Job: '
            || j
            || 'MGR: '
            || m
            || ' Hiredate: '
            || h
            || ' Salary: '
            || s
            || ' Comissao: '
            || cm);
    END;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT ENAME, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm FROM EMP)
    LOOP
        empregados (i.ename,
                    i.job,
                    i.mgr,
                    i.hiredate,
                    i.sal,
                    i.comm);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: But I want all rows and not one this is my difficulty

Comment: Just added an update to print all employees